# partition by multiple expressions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

With reference to syntax of [ROW_NUMBER Window Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) following is mentioned about PARTITION BY:-

```
PARTITION BY expr_list
```

Optional. One ***or more expressions*** that define the ROW_NUMBER function.

I am looking to understand how following would work, if **expr_list** has more than one expression within Partition By :-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_WF_ROW_NUMBER_WF.html

*Lets say, if following is replaced :-*

```
row_number() over (partition by sellerid order by qty asc) as row
```

*by following:-*

```
row_number() over (partition by sellerid,salesid order by qty asc) as row
```

**Then how partition by would create partition using multiple expressions?**

Comment: As you are quoting the Amazon Redshift manual I removed the tags for the incompatible databases

Answer (score 4):

The `PARTITION BY` clause determines what column(s) will be used to define a given partition.  This might be explained with some sample data:

```
sellerid | salesid | qty
1        | 1       | 1
1        | 2       | 10
1        | 3       | 5
2        | 4       | 10
2        | 5       | 7
```

Consider your first and second queries:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sellerid ORDER BY qty) rn1
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sellerid, salesid ORDER BY qty) rn2
```

This would generate the following values:

```
sellerid | salesid | qty | rn1 | rn2
1        | 1       | 1   | 1   | 1
1        | 2       | 10  | 3   | 1
1        | 3       | 5   | 2   | 1
2        | 4       | 10  | 2   | 1
2        | 5       | 7   | 1   | 1
```

In the first case, we generate separate row number series for each seller.  This series, in turn, is ordered ascending by the quantity.  In the second case, the series is redefined to be the combination of `sellerid` and `salesid`.  Because this combination is actually always unique for the entire table, the row number generated is just always 1.

As you can probably tell, there wouldn't be much point in using the second version of `ROW_NUMBER` here.  In general, you would use it if, for example, a given seller *and* sale could have more than one row, and you wanted to assign a sequence to those multiple rows.

Verified:-

[image: Verified SQL code]

Answer (score 0):

Same way that GROUP BY works:

```
--example data
letter, number, bool
a, 10, true
a, 10, false
b, 10, true
b, 10, false
b, 20, true
b, 20, false


--count(*) GROUP  BY letter
a, 2
b, 4

--count(*) GROUP BY letter, number
a, 10, 2
b, 10, 2
b, 20, 2
```

In the group by, the unique combinations of the column values are counted.

- When we `group by letter` the grouping keys are `a` and `b`.
- When we `group by letter, number` the grouping keys are `a,10`, `b,10` and `b,20`

If I were to row_number this:

```
--row_number() over(partition by letter ...)
a, 1
a, 2
b, 1
b, 2
b, 3
b, 4

--row_number() over(partition by letter, number ...)
a, 10, 1
a, 10, 2
b, 10, 1
b, 10, 2
b, 20, 1
b, 20, 2
```